# Kato inequality

Tags: harmonic-functions

For any real-valued smooth function $u$, we have the Kato inequality

$|\nabla|\nabla u||^2\leq(\operatorname{trace}(\operatorname{Hess}(u)))^2$,

which holds when $|\nabla u|\neq0$.

If moreover $u$ is harmonic (in an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$), how would the Kato inequality be improved to

$|\nabla|\nabla u||^2\leq\frac{n−1}{n}(\operatorname{trace}(\operatorname{Hess}(u)))^2$ ?

Comment: It should be worth mentioning that this was also asked at MO [link](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/110184/refined-kato-inequality)

Comment: This question has been asked on MO and has answers there.